# A new folder is created with default setgid bit set to S

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have two Ubuntu servers, both with umask 0002. On one of them, whenever I created a new sub-folder in a folder named `public`, the new sub-folder has the setgid bit set to `S`. On the other machine, it is `s`.

`ls -al ./public` shows the same filemodes on both machines:

```
drwxrwsr-x+ pi grp1 4096 Nov 27 15:36 .
drwxrwsr-x+ pi grp1 4096 Nov 14 21:56 ..
```

Which setting creates this difference? How do I make the `S` one have new folders created with `s`?